# Python: insert variable value into a "complicated" JSON string

Tags: python, json

I need help for inserting a variable into a json string with some special characters.
The result should look like this:

```py
http://192.168.1.254:8765/jsonrpc?request={"jsonrpc":"2.0", "id":1, "method": "Player.Open", "params":{"item":{"file":"http://utpdehls01-i.akamaihd.net/hls/live/220551/utpdehls01/Assets_1435171393171/Layer3_master.m3u8?hdnts=st=1436056150~exp=1436061550~acl=*/hls/live/220551/utpdehls01/*~hmac=6a0c67f479d1e048a0448fcc68a07b4003cb0fc58d088f7b265e0baab9ec4e6c"}}}
```

The variable is this part of the string:

```
my_variable = http://utpdehls01-i.akamaihd.net/hls/live/220551/utpdehls01/Assets_1435171393171/Layer3_master.m3u8?hdnts=st=1436056150~exp=1436061550~acl=*/hls/live/220551/utpdehls01/*~hmac=6a0c67f479d1e048a0448fcc68a07b4003cb0fc58d088f7b265e0baab9ec4e6c
```

What I tried so far:

```py
import json
    hostname = my_variable
    data = {'http://192.168.1.254:8765/jsonrpc?request={"jsonrpc":"2.0", "id":1, "method": "Player.Open", "params":{"item":{"file"': hostname}
    json.dumps(data)
```

But I only get something like this as output:

```json
'{"http://192.168.1.254:8765/jsonrpc?request={\\"jsonrpc\\":\\"2.0\\"}, \\"id\\":1, \\"method\\": \\"Player.Open\\", \\"params\\":{\\"item\\"}:{\\"fil
e\\"}": "http://utpdehls01-i.akamaihd.net/hls/live/220551/utpdehls01/Assets_1435171393171/Layer3_master.m3u8?hdnts=st=1436056150~exp=1436061550~acl=*/
hls/live/220551/utpdehls01/*~hmac=6a0c67f479d1e048a0448fcc68a07b4003cb0fc58d088f7b265e0baab9ec4e6c"}'
```

thanks in advance

Comment: So what is the issue?

Comment: That is what you get from your data structure. Do you expect anything else?

Comment: The output should be formatted, like the first code example.
The problem is, how to insert "my_variable" into the json string, to get exactly the result, like in the first code example

Comment: To be more precise (hopefully), this is the json string, how it should look like:
`code` http://192.168.1.254:8765/jsonrpc?request={"jsonrpc":"2.0", "id":1, "method": "Player.Open", "params":{"item":{"file":"my_variable"}}}